# For what kind of Q & A can Wikipedia be used as valid and only reference?

Tags: discussion, support, sources-and-citations, declined-flags

Here's how one of my recent flags was handled by a mod.

> Wikipedia is not a reliable source, needs a citation banner – sv. Feb 23 at 19:16
>
> **declined** - **wiki can be quoted for this question.**

A similar flag from a few weeks ago was handled differently:

> Multiple unsupported claims. Only references are to Wikipedia articles. Needs a citation banner. – sv. Feb 1 at 3:40   **helpful**

Does this mean Wikipedia can now be used as the only/primary source for answering for certain types of questions? If yes, what exactly are those types?

Comment: oh looks like wiki was quoted in the question. If it is so, then I think it is fine. Otherwise, if it is in the answer then that flag shouldn't be declined.

Comment: "oh looks like wiki was quoted in the question" -- How did you come to that conclusion? Wikipedia was cited in the answer only. Mod who handled the flag says Wikipedia can be considered as a valid source for the concerned question (to which the flagged answer was posted).@Mr_Green

Comment: oh ok, I thought so because of mention of question here - "wiki can be quoted for this **question**". my bad.

Comment: But in what circumstances we are allowing wiki source answers? This is new to me

Comment: It must be an ad hoc case. Generally Wiki is not accepted as a valid source. It is reasonable for us to comment on the flag handling by the mod only when we know what was the question and what was the answer.@Mr_Green

Comment: @sv. add the post links for better clarity.